# Erro ocorrendo em versões de API específicas

Tags: android, api, android-studio, sdk

Quando eu crio um projeto novo 
[image: Criando Projeto novo]

E escolho a mínima SDK 10
[image: SS]

Ele cria o pacote de Android com o `main.java` e `activy_main.xml` (e outras coisas)
só que quando ele compila os códigos da esses erros e não sei o porquê. Testei até a API 16 e funcionou o min SDK sem esse erro. As APIs 10, 8 e 7 quando cria-se o projeto, dão este erro:
[image: SS]

[image: SS]

[image: SS]

SDKS TOOLS E EXTRAS QUE POSSUO(TODOS INSTALADOS PELO SDK MANAGER)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Terminando de instalar a API 15 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Build.gradle ( APP )

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.guga.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}

Build.gradle ("Nome do Aplicativo")

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Quais SDK's você instalou (usando o SDK Manager)? Além disso, quais **Extras** você instalou? Inclua essas informações em sua pergunta.

Comment: Wakim Usei sim o SDK Manager(tenho as API 10 16 17 18 19 20 todas as tools e extras) (Tando o do ADT-BUNDLE como o do android Studio)eu possou todos os Extras instalados... (Vou acrecentar imagens agora)

Comment: Esse excesso de imagens não dificulta a interpretação do problema, não?

Comment: Boa Noite amigo, Creio que nao dificulta as imagens de cima sao as do erro e as 4 ultimas sao dos arquivos que eu possou no meu computador...; (eu particularmente nao achei dificil de se entender)

Comment: Gustavo, infelizmente estive sem tempo para ver o problema. Olhando as imagens, você não colocou a seção do Android 5, baixou também? Como esta seu `build.gradle`? Poderia incluir na pergunta (texto)?

Comment: Wakim o que seria essa seção do Android 5 ???
Ja coloquei os Build.gradle

Comment: Gustavo, seria a seção com os arquivos do Android 5.0 (21). Você expandiu todos, menos esse, não deu pra ver se você baixou o SDK 21 ou não.

Comment: Wakim nao possuia o SDK 21, mas ja estou baixando ele...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estou passando para informar que consegui resolver o meu problema com as api antigas no caso a 10 que era a que eu precisava que estava dando problema.... eu nao entendi direito o porque desse erro, mas o que me resolveu o problema foi a API 21 (Android 5.0) eu nao a possuia instalada no computador e quando eu a coloquei parou de dar os erros na api 10 
eu fiz o teste desinstalando para ver se era isso mesmo ou outra coisa e realmente era esse o meu problema, Caso alguem tenha algum problema parecido o que me ajudou a resolver foi isso.

Agradeço a todos que tentaram me Ajudar aqui.